# ASP .net MVC5 - CSS styling issue- "@Html.ValidationMessageFor"

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc-5

My problem is styling a server generated validation message, the padding displays the background color before the message is generated, when the padding is removed, the background-color is no longer visible.

I want to have the padding in the code for styling purposes, but without showing any content or background color as this is a validation message, here is the code as follows:

```
<div class="validate">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)</div>
```

css:

```
.validate {color:#ecf0f1;font-size:.9em;background-color:#e74c3c;padding:10px;}
```

Before validation:

[image: before]

What occurs after the validation shows up:

[image: after]

What I want before validation:

[image: what i want]

Comment: In *site.css* change the ***.field-validation-error*** to your required style. You do not need to create a new class. Doing so you won't need to worry about your problem

Comment: ok thank you for that, I did this but now the background color does not span the whole div, as seen in the screenshot.

Comment: added a demo fiddle for your reference. Please share the rendered HTML of your code if still not works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with modifying the class:

```
.field-validation-error
```

By adding:

```
{display: inline-block;  width:100%;
color:#ecf0f1;
font-size:.9em;
background-color:#e74c3c;
padding:10px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

that's because of the `Div` that you've `ValidationMessage` inside and CSS applied on that div.

**try this CSS:**

```
.validate:not(:empty)
 {
   color:#ecf0f1;
   font-size:.9em;
   background-color:#e74c3c;
   padding:10px;
 }
```

**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sunnykumar08/YwDNz/)**

Comment: :not :empty, did not do anything visually, is there something missing?

Comment: oops... please note: it's **:not(:empty)** and not **:not :empty**